# My yeast recipies seem to harden somewhat after baking

Tags: bread

I am using a kichen Aid dough hook machine. I made some great cinnamon rolls, but after they cool they become somewhat hard to the touch. I can reheat in the microwave for about 15 seconds and they become perfectly soft as they should be. Am I missing something in the preparation?

Comment: Unless you are doing something very unusual to the prepared rolls (e.g. cooling in the fridge), it is probably a problem with the recipe, I would say low hydration is the most probable culprit. Can you post the whole recipe please?

Answer (score 3):

Using a dough hook versus hand-kneading won't make your bread harden after baking. If your rolls are hardening then you have either overcooked them, or there's not enough water in the dough. This can happen for several reasons:

- The recipe doesn't call for enough water. Use a different recipe or add a bit more water to the one you have
- The flour your are using is a higher protein content than the recipe is designed for. Gluten is a protein, and higher protein flours use more water. This isn't a bad thing necessarily, gluten makes your bread stretchy. The answer is the same: add more water
- You are adding too much flour when kneading. I made this mistake for years! When you put flour on your surface to keep it from sticking you are reducing the moisture content of your dough as you work it in. This can turn a dough dry very quickly. If you want flour to knead with then reserve some of the recipe flour, but don't use more. Some doughs are meant to be sticky. If you want to keep it from sticking knead with oil instead. Personally, I let the dough stick and use that stickiness to stretch the glutens, it makes for faster kneading that way

Comment: I disagree with the second point. I have made bread with extremely high gluten content (got careless when calculating the amount of vital gluten I was adding to the AP flour) and it is *not* hard. It gets kind of rubbery and slightly translucent on the inside, but still soft. But good catch on the overcooking possibility, it is also a major reason for being hard.

Comment: I'm not saying that higher gluten content makes anything hard, simply that it uses more moisture. Some recipes will work fine with that, others may be affected.

Comment: I am thinking it could be the liquid content. The recipe called for milk. I actually doubled the milk from 1 cup to 2 cups. I have been using King Arthur flour and I have been using it while kneading. Would water be a better substitute? As for the baking, I am baking at 350 with a pre heated oven in a glass pie pan. I am baking to a slight golden brown for about 20 minutes or so.